# How to fetch in subquerys with the ID of the current row?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I'm very new at SQL and I have a question with a problem that I'm having that I don't know how to fix (Btw I'm new at SQL).

So I have these tables:

```
TABLE 1 - Users
-ID     -NAME
1       User1       
2       User2       
3       User3       



TABLE 2 - JOBS
-ID     -JOB                    -USER       -ID_DIRECCTION
1       Football Match          User1       1                  
2       Bascketball Match       User3       1                   
3       Swimming Race           User2       2                   
4       Handball Game           User3       2                   
5       Tennis Match            User2       3                   



TABLE 3 - DIRECCTIONS
-ID     -DIRECCTION         -NUMBER
1       Fail Street         34
2       Swimming Street     45
3       Fake Street         01
```

What I want to do is to show the Table of Jobs but adding a new column with a SELECT that shows the last user that have been on the direcction (If no one has been in the direcction the result will be null) and if are multiple users the most recent one.

I'm close to get it with my current query (i think), but the main problem is that when I do the subquery there's a way to fetch the inner query with the ID of the current row where's executing the main query??

```
SELECT j.ID, j.JOB, j.USER, j.ID_DIRECCTION,
(SELECT j.USER
FROM USERS u INNER JOIN
     JOBS j
     ON j.USER = u.ID INNER JOIN
     DIRECCTIONS d
     ON d.ID = j.ID_DIRECCTION
WHERE d.ID = (SELECT d.ID FROM DIRECCTIONS WHERE d.ID = j.ID_DIRECCTION --I want this to be current ID_DIRECCTION row)  
ORDER BY j.ID DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
) AS LAST_USER
FROM JOBS j;
```

**How is the way to select the ID of the current row to fetch other things in subquerys????**

The result should be like:

```
-ID     -JOB                    -USER       -ID_DIRECCTION      -LAS_TUSER
1       Football Match          User1       1                   null*
2       Bascketball Match       User3       1                   User1*
3       Swimming Race           User2       2                   null*
4       Handball Game           User3       2                   User2*
5       Tennis Match            User2       3                   User3*
```

But I'm always getting the same value in LAST_USER

Comment: Is about Oracle, sorry I missed the tag :/, fixed it. @GuidoG

Comment: why is the `LAS_TUSER = User3` for Tennis Match? where did it come from in the direction 3?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included real, or at least valid and conisstent, table, data and results. Both `user` and `number` are invalid column names, and does yout `jobs` table really duplicate the user name or is that an ID that points to the `users` table? Your query is invalid for several reasons and doesn't match the tables you described. All of that makes it harder to see what you really need and what you are really stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want `LAG`, but it isn't fully clear why `LAS_TUSER = User3` for Tennis Match (job id 5)

```
SELECT j.*, 
       LAG(u.name) 
         over ( 
           PARTITION BY j.id_direcction 
           ORDER BY j.id ) 
FROM   users u 
       inner join jobs j 
               ON j.username = u.name 
ORDER  BY j.id
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/072058/3)

Comment: If the jobs table really has the user name denomarlised (I'm not convinced....) then you don't even need the join. [Modified Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/072058/4).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question whether you really have the user name in the jobs table, or just the ID.

If you do have the name then you have all th einformation you need in the jobs table and [you can just use `lag()`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/072058/4).

But if you have the ID then you need to join to the users table, for both the current and lag IDs. You can still get the previous ID the same way:

```
select id, job, id_user, id_direcction,
  lag(id_user) over (partition by id_direcction order by id) as last_id_user
from jobs
```

but then use that as a CTE or inline view, and join from that:

```
select j.id, j.job, u.name, j.id_direcction, lu.name as last_name
from (
  select id, job, id_user, id_direcction,
    lag(id_user) over (partition by id_direcction order by id) as last_id_user
  from jobs
) j
join users u on u.id = j.id_user
left join users lu on lu.id = j.last_id_user
```

With CTEs to provide the sample data, and making assumptions about what those really hold:

```
-- sample data
with users (id, name) as (
            select 1, 'User1' from dual
  union all select 2, 'User2' from dual
  union all select 3, 'User3' from dual
),
jobs (id, job, id_user, id_direcction) as (
            select 1, 'Football Match', 1, 1 from dual
  union all select 2, 'Bascketball Match', 3, 1 from dual
  union all select 3, 'Swimming Race', 2, 2 from dual
  union all select 4, 'Handball Game', 3, 2 from dual
  union all select 5, 'Tennis Match', 2, 3 from dual
)
-- actual query
select j.id, j.job, u.name, j.id_direcction, lu.name as last_name
from (
  select id, job, id_user, id_direcction,
    lag(id_user) over (partition by id_direcction order by id) as last_id_user
  from jobs
) j
join users u on u.id = j.id_user
left join users lu on lu.id = j.last_id_user
order by j.id;

        ID JOB               NAME  ID_DIRECCTION LAST_
---------- ----------------- ----- ------------- -----
         1 Football Match    User1             1      
         2 Bascketball Match User3             1 User1
         3 Swimming Race     User2             2      
         4 Handball Game     User3             2 User2
         5 Tennis Match      User2             3
```

You don't need to refer to the `direcctions` table unless you want to get its description. I've included a version that does that [in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a3658c67c039c2db050b33c36e2383b).

Like @KaushikNayak, I don't see how or why you would expect to see `User3` against the last row, based on the data you provided.